# expecting a left angle bracket, found 'children' in regel 5 kolom 16

Tags: apex

```
public class HierarchyNode {

    public HierarchyNode parent;
    public Account node;
    public List children;

    HierarchyNode(Account acc, HierarchyNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.node = acc;
        this.children = new List();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious answer, answering it for second time!!

Hope your question doesn't get deleted this time ;)

```
public class HierarchyNode {

    public HierarchyNode parent;
    public Account node;
    public List<HierarchyNode> children;

    HierarchyNode(Account acc, HierarchyNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.node = acc;
        this.children = new List<HierarchyNode>();
    }
}
```

Comment: To be ruthlessly specific, this was a syntax error in the declaration of a `List`. From [the documentation on Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm),  the syntax for declaring a list is either `<type name>[] <variable name>` (i.e. `String[] myStringList`) or `List<<type name>> <variable name>` (i.e. `List<String> myStringList`). As `public List children` does not conform to either of those forms, an error was thrown. Adding the type of  the things stored inside the list (inside angle brackets) resolves the error.